# Getting class name from static function in abstract class

Tags: php, class, static, abstract

I have an abstract class that has a number of static functions (which return a new instance of itself by using `new static($args)` which works fine), but I can't work out how to get the class name. I am trying to avoid putting

```
protected static $cn = __CLASS__;
```

but if unavoidable, then its not the end of the world

```
abstract class ExtendableObject {
    static function getObject() {
        return new static($data);
    }

    static function getSearcher() {
        return new ExtendableObjectFinder(/* CLASS NAME CLASS */);
    }
}

class ExtendableObjectFinder {
    private $cn;

    function __construct($className) {
       $this->cn = $className;
    }

    function where($where) { ... }

    function fetch() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Can you outline the original intent? Chances are there is an easy way to get the class name, but what's the purpose of getting the class name for your implementation? There may be a better pattern to use than what you're trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the name of the class you can use [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) and pass `$this`.

Alternatively, there is [`get_called_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) which you can use within static methods.

Comment: @cgoddard: My impression was this is a form of a singleton, and they could pass the reference to `get_class`. I may have read it wrong (still pre-coffee) but `get_class` would avoid `__CLASS__` (assuming an instance is available). [You don't generally return `new static($args)` if the entire class is static, btw]

Comment: at this point, it has not been instantiated, but it does later

Comment: @cgoddard: How about [`get_called_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the class name explicitly, you can use `self`.

```
class SomeClass {

    private static $instance;

    public static function getInstance() {

          if (self::$instance) {
               // ...
          }

    }

}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/k9ox5EN4).

Comment: @cgoddard Are you subclassing it?